# NGINX configuration help needed. IP address works. Domain name displays NGINX default configuration

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, linode

I have an issue which has been driving me insane all weekend. I have deployed my Django Rest Framework API using Ubuntu / NGINX / gunicorn. The API works and can be seen when you visit the IP (http://213.219.38.17/). However, when I visit the site using my purchase domain ([www.conorbaileyapi.xyz](http://www.conorbaileyapi.xyz)) the NGINX default page is displayed.

I purchased the domain 'conorbaileyapi.xyz' from Namecheap and added the correct name server records and added the A Records to the Linode server.

My Allowed hosts list in my Django project is as follows:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['213.219.38.17', 'conorbaileyapi.xyz', 'www.conorbaileyapi.xyz']
```

My NGINX server block is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name conorbaileyapi.xyz www.conorbaileyapi.xyz 213.219.38.17;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/conor/api/django-rest-api/blog;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/conor/api/django-rest-api/blog/blog.sock;
    }
}
```

Thanks you in advance for you help.

Conor

Comment: Clear the browser cache or try from the incognito window.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken care of the DNS redirection? When you buy a new domain, one of the first steps is to use the domain management panel, in this case the Namecheap panel, to specify that the domain points to the IP of the web server.

Note that once the change in the DNS may take hours to be implemented, it is not immediate.